# How to prevent CSRF in API-Centric Web Application

Tags: rest, security, csrf, api-design

I am looking to build a web application using API-Centric architecture.

The frontend of the application would make requests to the REST API using AJAX.

How could I implement a robust CSRF prevention strategy for this application?

Comment: How does your API authenticate clients? Bearer token? Session id or token in a cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some proposition: First You can use api-url like `GET api/gime-csrf` which return CSRF token as response and also set it in `http-only` cookie (so JS has no access to it - but remember to block TRACE request in server to prevent XST attack). Then when you make some "save state" request like POST/PUT/PATCH - you just put CSRF in some request header - and in server you compare header token value with cookie token value.